# Exit status code 1 Unable to send email

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm attempting to send an email out to the person(s) who register for my site using the Email Class provided with Codeigniter for my project. I am receiving the following error message.

```
Exit status code: 1
Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.
Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to sendmail using this method.

$this->email->message('Welcome to '.$this->config->item('company_name').', "\r\n" Thank you for joining the '.$this->config->item('company_name').' team. We have listed your registration details below. Make sure you save this email. To verify this account please click the following link. "\r\n" '.anchor('register/verify/'.$registration_key, 'Click Here To Activate Your Account', '').' "\r\n" Please verfiy your account within 2 hours, otherwise your registration will become invalid and you will have to register again. "\r\n" Your email address: '.$post_email_address.' "\r\n" Your Password: '.$post_password.' "\r\n" Enjoy your stay here at '.$this->config->item('company_name').' "\r\n" The '.$this->config->item('company_name').' Team');
```

**UPDATE :**

I am updating my code because for some reason I am still receiving an the same error and I can't figure out what it is that is giving me the error.

```
../application/configs/site_configs.php
<?php

$config['company_name'] = 'My Test Site';
$config['comapny_email'] = 'owner@testingsite.com';
```

I would also like to mention here that I am autoloading my site configs file.

```
$autoload['config'] = array('site_configs');
```

Register Controller

```
// User was successfully created and the user needs to verify their account.
// Send registered an email informing them how to validate their account.
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from($this->config->item('company_email'), $this->config->item('company_name'));
$this->email->to($post_email_address);
$this->email->subject($this->config->item('company_name').' Registration');
//$message = 'Welcome to '. $this->config->item('company_name') ."\r\n";
//$message .= 'Thank you for joining the ' . $this->config->item('company_name') . ' team.';
//$message .= 'We have listed your registration details below. Make sure you save this email.';
//$message .= 'To verify this account please click the following link.'."\r\n";
//$message .= anchor('register/verify/'.$registration_key, 'Click Here To Activate Your Account', '')."\r\n";
//$message .= 'Please verfiy your account within 2 hours, otherwise your registration will become invalid and you will have to register again.'."\r\n";
//$message .= 'Your email address: '.$post_email_address."\r\n";
//$message .= 'Your Password: '.$post_password."\r\n";
//$message .= 'Enjoy your stay here at '.$this->config->item('company_name')."\r\n";
//$message .= 'The '.$this->config->item('company_name').' Team';
$this->email->message('Great registration.' /*$message */);
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: Ok, first things first.. when you echo out `$this->config->item('company_email')` or the other one just by themselves.. does anything print out?

Comment: next.. this seems to be a quirk with either PHP or CI not sure which but sometimes depending on what your doing.. a parameter of a function being defined by a function, trips things up. I notice this a lot with the session stuff in CI

Comment: try, `$comp_email = $this->config->item('company_email');` `$comp_name = $this->config->item('company_name');` `$this->email->from($comp_email, $comp_name);`

Comment: I attempted to do so and for some reason did not get my expected results. Both returned false still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also try to have your code be a little more readable.. I notice, your gigantic string for the message is riddled with continuations going in and out of dynamic variables. Chaining the string together as it goes along.

Why not try

```
$message = 'Welcome to '. $this->config->item('company_name') ."\r\n";
$message .= 'Thank you for joining the ' . $this->config->item('company_name') . ' team.';
$message .= 'We have listed your registration details below. Make sure you save this email.';
$message .= 'To verify this account please click the following link.'."\r\n";
$message .= .anchor('register/verify/'.$registration_key, 'Click Here To Activate Your Account', '')."\r\n";
$message .= 'Please verfiy your account within 2 hours, otherwise your registration will become invalid and you will have to register again.'."\r\n";
$message .= 'Your email address: '.$post_email_address."\r\n";
$message .= 'Your Password: '.$post_password."\r\n";
$message .= 'Enjoy your stay here at '.$this->config->item('company_name')."\r\n";
$message .= 'The '.$this->config->item('company_name').' Team';



$this->email->message($message);
```

Where its a bit more manageable and readable. So you can see where your missing a single or double quote or where you might be missing a period that would chain string to variable, etc..

The only thing Im not sure about is one line had `.anchor()` not sure if thats a function or something else but didn't look complete.

Comment: I may or may not have caught everything, but from the clean up I attempted, there was a lot of break points in that one original string. That could have overall broke the email function your using prematurely making it think something was a different setting/parameter for it then what was actually being provided..

Comment: Great answer here however I still get the same error message and when I comment each line to see where the error might be coming from I comment out the whole message and put a hardcoded value in for the message method and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your server has sendmail and it is correctly set up or install sendmail package in your server

```
yum install sendmail
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

Make your, user email id is valid, will not send e-mail if sender does not exist

send a testmail,   `echo "test sendmail" | sendmail xxx@yy.com`

Comment: Server already uses sendmail. WHen I run regular emails it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->load->library('email');

    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'example@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


    $this->email->from('example@gmail.com', 'easyfact');
    $this->email->to('example@gmail.com');
    $this->email->cc('example@gmail.com');
    $this->email->bcc('example@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: yes. This would likely work sending email via gmail account or google business account. But what if the OP wants to have @his-domain.com? and its neither google business or gmail.com? Some people like to have brand ability. Also, if ya muck up somewhere, and something exploits your scripts, you could get your email locked out..